# WCF - set endpoint from client code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, communication

I'm just learning WCF and I'd like to write application where client is on different PC than host. I wrote client and server on the same PC first and it works fine (tutorial from msdn +-), here si code:

Service

IService1.cs

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            // Code added to write output to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Subtract({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Multiply({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Divide({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Host
 - I added all necessary references.

```
namespace GettingStartedHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");

            // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

            try
            {
                // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Step 5 Start the service.
                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally client

```
namespace GettingStartedClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Step 1: Create an instance of the WCF proxy.
            CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();
            Console.ReadLine();
            // Step 2: Call the service operations.
            // Call the Add service operation.
            double value1 = 100.00D;
            double value2 = 15.99D;
            double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Subtract service operation.
            value1 = 145.00D;
            value2 = 76.54D;
            result = client.Subtract(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Subtract({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Multiply service operation.
            value1 = 9.00D;
            value2 = 81.25D;
            result = client.Multiply(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Multiply({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Divide service operation.
            value1 = 22.00D;
            value2 = 7.00D;
            result = client.Divide(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Divide({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            //Step 3: Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources.
            client.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I added Service Reference too (Add service reference - Discover - select and ok).

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/GettingStartedLib/Service1/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Im little bit confused, becouse in app.config is different adress, than i set in host `Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");`, but it works, so ok...

Now i want to make, the client set endpoint in the running client app, so first i wanted write something easy, so i try this (from another stackoverflow page):

```
namespace GettingStartedClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Step 1: Create an instance of the WCF proxy.
            Console.ReadLine();

            EndpointIdentity spn = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/mikev-ws");
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/GettingStartedLib/Service1/");
            var address = new EndpointAddress(uri, spn);
            var client = new CalculatorClient("WSHttpBinding_IEchoService", address);

            // Step 2: Call the service operations.
            // Call the Add service operation.
            double value1 = 100.00D;
            double value2 = 15.99D;
            double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Subtract service operation.
            value1 = 145.00D;
            value2 = 76.54D;
            result = client.Subtract(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Subtract({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Multiply service operation.
            value1 = 9.00D;
            value2 = 81.25D;
            result = client.Multiply(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Multiply({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            // Call the Divide service operation.
            value1 = 22.00D;
            value2 = 7.00D;
            result = client.Divide(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Divide({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);

            //Step 3: Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources.
            client.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

.... but it dropped. Can someone help me how to set it? In final version of this project I'd like to have client app, where client set IP of server and then can call the operation from the server(host).

Comment: Ok, now i see.. I fergot client.Open().. but Im still confused of the adress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own. This is my solution. First I had to change localhost to my IP and Http binding in host to basicHttpBindig:

```
   selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new BasicHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
```

Then i had to remove my service reference from client and add new service reference for this new host, so my App.config changed to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />

            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ip:8000/PokusWPF/CalculatorService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And finally I change this in the client:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://ip:8000/PokusWPF/CalculatorService");
            var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
            var client = new CalculatorClient();
            client.Endpoint.Address = address;
            client.Open();
```

Everything works on different PCs now. I hope it will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the server name/ip-address of the machine where your service is hosted:

for example you configurations:

also your code : Uri baseAddress = new Uri"http://**{ServerName/Ip-Address}**/GettingStarted/

Comment: I have set my ip and change code in client to
`Uri uri = new Uri("http://ip/PokusWPF/CalculatorService");`
           `var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);`
            `var client = new CalculatorClient();`
            `client.Endpoint.Address = address;`
           `client.Open();`
and it works on one PC, but when I start client on different PC, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the remote/client PC is in proper network through LAN or through internet, verify first your service by opening on the client pc in the web browser like Internet explorer etc. When it starts working in any web browser then it will also work in  client application.

Verify your hosting of service, try hosting the same in IIS etc, if it is self hosted the make sure the ports are proper and remote requests are using proper ports.